# Setting up a if else statement with button in fragment, FuzFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

First I must say that I'm not good in English and "completely new" to Android Programming.

I want to create an app that can monitor server performance. I have use the navigation drawer as my app interface. Each have a few fragment running with different sets of activity. One of the fragment, I would like to create an activity that can calculate the server performance using some if else statement calculation with a button to submit the results. When I run my app, I have trouble with this fragment (FuzFragment) where my app stopped immediately with an error "Unfortunately, ServerMonitorApp has stopped".

Below, is the fragment class (FuzFragment) that I used to display the layout:

```
package com.example.servermonitorapp;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FuzFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuz,
                container, false);

        Button sumButton = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        sumButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText cpu = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.textCPU);
                EditText ram = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.textRAM);
                TextView res = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

                int cpuslow = Integer.parseInt(cpu.getText().toString());
                int cpusmedium = Integer.parseInt(cpu.getText().toString());
                int cpushigh = Integer.parseInt(cpu.getText().toString());
                int ramlow = Integer.parseInt(ram.getText().toString());
                int rammedium = Integer.parseInt(ram.getText().toString());
                int ramhigh = Integer.parseInt(ram.getText().toString());

                if (cpuslow > 0 && cpuslow <= 30 | ramlow > 0 && ramlow <= 23) {
                    res.setText("Safe");

                } else if (cpusmedium > 30 && cpusmedium <= 60 | rammedium > 23 && rammedium <= 38) {
                    res.setText("Risk");

                } else if (cpushigh > 60 | ramhigh > 38) {
                    res.setText("Very Risk");

                } else {
                    res.setText("Invalid Number");
                }

            }
        });
        return mLinearLayout;
    }
    }
```

Is there any wrong with my code that can cause my app stopped responding? Need help so much on this since I'm still in learning in Android programming.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Android the dark side of development haha ;).
Ok let's go through a few basics.

The onCreate method is used to inflate or draw your layout. prior to having your layout drawn (if you do a findViewById) it won't exist.

In order for the onCreate method to draw the picture it needs the setContent method called that is created by default. This should be one of if not the first line of code you call. It ensures everything is available after that line for UI related interactions of an ACTIVITY. Emphasis on activity because the rules change when you get into fragments.

Now, the next issue is you have bloated code. Doing things like.

```
EditText myText = findViewById(R.id.myText);
int myValue = Integer.parseInt(myText.getText.toString());
```

etc.. can all be done in the same line and you are not using the reference to myText anywhere else so just do it like:

```
int myValue = Integer.parseInt(findViewById(R.id.myText).getText.toString());
```

Keep in mind I am doing Pseudo code. Please don't be that person that replies with " you have an error in your code " haha or I will not help.

Next up, it appears you never did the setContentView method in your onCreate, please put that back and set the content to your activity.xml code that matches the layout that you are inflating.

Next up, you are doing findViewById inside a button click. This is unnecessary repeat code. If you need to use the textView over and over then store a reference to it to avoid the repetitive lookup.

```
class MyClass{

EditText myTextBox;

protected void onCreate(stuff){
     myTextBox = findViewById(R,id.myTextBox);

     findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()){
            @Override
            protected void onClick(){
                 int myValue = Integer.parseInt(myTextBox.getText().toString());
            }

     });
}
```

Also for the record the onCreate should be very clean and to the point. I typically have a syncUI method that does my findViewById calls "prior to data binding days". I don't do that anymore, but new guys learning is fine.

Then in my syncUI I call wrapper methods to handle click listening instead of nesting in onCreate, but for now you are learning. But if you want a quick example..

```
onCreate(){
   setContentView(myViewPointer from the R File);
   syncUI();

}

private void syncUI(){
    //SETUP TEXTVIEWS OR OTHER UIs that you need
    //get btnSubmit reference from findViewByid

    btnSubmit_onClick(); //called one time in onCreate to wrap the click listener into method that allows it to collapse and be easily found.
}

private btnSubmit_onClick(){
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         protected void onClick(){
              //handle Clicks
         }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sam for your reply..

I hv figure out one of my issue that cause my fragment stop responding when I run my app is might due to I mistaken declare my layout as LinearLayout in code above where else my actual layout in the myfragment.xml file is in Relativelayout (shown below).

```js
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuz,
                container, false);
```

After I correct it my app can be open and the fragment related above also able to open. Only there's still problem when I try to run the code using few number sample and my app stop responding with same error "Unfortunately, ServerMonitorApp has stopped".